# Update with Case or If condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using PL/sql on APEX.
I have a simple table, where one of the column I need to update the field using Case or if condition.
Just can't this right.

e.g.

```
Update TableAA 
set column1 = 
Select case
when SUBSTR(column2,-5,5) ='xxx11'  then 'xx1xx'
when SUBSTR(column2,-4,4) = 'y1y1' then 'yyyy'
else '9999999' end as column1
from TableAA;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are updating records from same table, why not try:

```
Update TableAA set column1 = 
  case 
   when SUBSTR(column2,-5,5) ='xxx11' then 'xx1xx' 
   when SUBSTR(column2,-4,4) = 'y1y1' then 'yyyy' 
  else '9999999' end;
```